# More efficient way to discretize 1D wave equation for FDM

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am using the finite difference method for solving the 1D wave equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - c^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

Here, I am using a separate discretization for the two partial derivatives - $A$ for the time derivative, and $B$ for the space derivative, where:

$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & & & & & \\\\
1 & -2 & 1 & & & \\\\
& 1 & -2 & 1 & & & \\\\
& & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\\\
& & & 1 & -2 & 1 & \\\\
& & & & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
AU = \frac{1}{h^2} \begin{bmatrix} D & & & & & \\\\ & D & & & & \\\\ & & D & &
& \\\\ & & & D & & \\\\ & & & & \ddots & \\\\ & & & & & D \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{1, 2} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{1, n - 1} \\\\ u_{1,
n} \\\\ u_{2, 1} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{m, n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
u_{1, 2} - 2u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{1, 3} - 2u_{1, 2} + u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{1, 4} -
2u_{1, 3} + u_{1, 2} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{i, 2} - 2u_{i, 1} \\\\ u_{i, 3} -
2u_{i, 2} + u_{i, 1} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{i, n} - 2u_{i, n - 1} + u_{i, n - 1}
\\\\ u_{i, n - 1} - 2 u_{i, n} \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
E = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & \dots & 1 & & & \\\\
1 & \dots & -2 & \dots & 1 & \\\\
& 1 & \dots & -2 & \dots & 1 & & \\\\
& & \ddots & \dots & \ddots & \dots & \ddots \\\\
& & & & 1 & \dots & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ BU = \frac{1}{h^2} \begin{bmatrix} E & & & & & \\\\ & E & & & & \\\\ & & E &
& & \\\\ & & & E & & \\\\ & & & & \ddots & \\\\ & & & & & E \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{1, 2} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{1, n - 1} \\\\ u_{1,
n} \\\\ u_{2, 1} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{m, n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
u_{2, 1} - 2u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{3, 1} - 2u_{2, 1} + u_{1, 1} \\\\ u_{4, 1} -
2u_{3, 1} + u_{2, 1} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{n - 1, 1} - 2u_{n, 1} \\\\ \vdots \\\\
u_{2, j} - 2u_{1, j} \\\\ u_{3, j} - 2u_{2, j} + u_{1, j} \\\\ u_{4, j} -
2u_{3, j} + u_{2, j} \\\\ \vdots \\\\ u_{n - 1, j} - 2u_{n, j} \\\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

This results in the matrix equation:

$$
(A - c^2 B) U = 0
$$

which can then be solved. However, there's got to be a more efficient way than this to do FDM on the wave equation, as every example I've seen using FDM only uses one matrix. Does anyone have any simpler methods?

Comment: Hint: let $w = (u, u_t)$ then you have a first-order linear system in $w$

Comment: @whpowell96 Ah yes, I see. Also, if I were to solve it the way I outlined, wouldn't $(A - c^2 B)U = 0$ always yield the solution $U = 0$?

Comment: It is certainly possible that the matrix $A-c^2B$ is singular. It seems that you have assumed some sort of end conditions at the initial and final time value so those discretizations may be incorrect, yielding inaccurate discrete soltuions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the suggested method of rewriting as a system of first-order PDEs, the wave equation can also be more efficiently discretized by using just one discretizing matrix - that is, a spatial discretization. By discretizing:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \Rightarrow AU
$$

Then the wave equation becomes an ordinary differential equation:

$$
U'' = c^2 AU
$$

Which can be solved using the standard techniques of solving ODEs.